# Alternatives to DbContext.Entry(foo).Reference(x=>x.Bar).Load()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are trying to Unit Test code and following on from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314431 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429 we are having issues where we are using `DbContext.Entry(foo).Reference(x=>x.Bar).Load()`

Same as this guy... https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2741 and related to my other question [Loading Related Entities in Mocked DbContext using Moq for Web Api 2 Controller Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515925/loading-related-entities-in-mocked-dbcontext-using-moq-for-web-api-2-controller) `DbContext.Entry` is causing us issues.

In our Api Controller we have the following Action

```
[ResponseType(typeof (Foo))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFoo(Foo foo)
{
 _db.Foos.Add(foo);
 _db.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Bar).Load();
 _db.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Qux).Load();
 await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
 return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new {id = foo.Id},foo);
}
```

We are only passing in the FK for `BarId` and `QuxId` e.g.

```
var newFoo = Foo{
    Name = "New Foo",
    BarId = 1,
    Bar = null,
    QuxId = 2
    Qux = null
}
```

but we need to bring back `Bar` and `Qux` e.g.

```
Foo {
    Name = "New Foo",
    BarId = 1,
    Bar = { BarId = 1, Name = "Super Bar", Description = "Super Bar 1"},
    QuxId = 2,
    Qux = { QuxId = 2, Name = "Super Qux", Description = "Super Qux 2"},
}
```

so are using `_db.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Bar).Load();`

What are the alternatives for bringing back related entities other than `_db.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Bar).Load();` or would I just be better off reading the record back after the  `await _db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Lazy Loading has been disabled.

Comment: I would suggest only to return the foo.Id and make another call to retrieve Foo with its dependencies loaded.

Comment: @dariogriffo I don't want to roundtrip the Api

Comment: Answered here in your previous question [Loading Related Entities in Mocked DbContext using Moq for Web Api 2 Controller Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36071549/5233410)

Answer (score 0):

Answered here in your previous question [Loading Related Entities in Mocked DbContext using Moq for Web Api 2 Controller Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36071549/5233410)

Replace

```
....
_db.Foos.Add(foo);
_db.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Bar).Load();
_db.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Qux).Load();
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
....
```

using an abstraction of that functionality

```
public interface IUnitOfWork {
    void Add<T>(T item) where T : class;
    void LoadRelatedEntity<T, TRelated>(T item, Expression<Func<T, TRelated>> exp)
        where T : class
        where TRelated : class;
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

like so

```
....
unitOfWork.Add(foo);
await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
unitOfWork.LoadRelatedEntity(foo, x => x.Bar);
unitOfWork.LoadRelatedEntity(foo, x => x.Qux);
....
```

And setup a test

```
[TestMethod] 
public async Task TestPostFoo() {
     //Arrange
     bool saved = false;
     var model = new Foo {
         Name = "New Foo",
         QuxId = 99,
         Qux = null,
         BarId = 66,
         Bar = null
     };
     var mockUnitOfWork = new Moq.Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
     mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync())
         .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(0))
         .Callback(() => {
             model.Id = 1;
             saved = true;
         });
     mockUnitOfWork
         .Setup(x => x.LoadRelatedEntity<Foo, Qux>(It.IsAny<Foo>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, Qux>>>()))
         .Callback(() => model.Qux = new Qux() { QuxId = 2, Name = "Super Qux", Description = "Super Qux 2"});
     mockUnitOfWork
         .Setup(x => x.LoadRelatedEntity<Foo, Bar>(It.IsAny<Foo>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>>>()))
         .Callback(() => model.Bar = new Bar() { BarId = 1, Name = "Super Bar", Description = "Super Bar 1"});

     var controller = new TestsFooApiController(mockUnitOfWork.Object);
     controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage { };
     controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

     //Act
     var result = await controller.PostFoo(model) as CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult<Foo>;

     //Assert
     result.Should().NotBeNull();
     result.Content.Should().NotBeNull();
     result.Content.Id.Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
     result.Content.Qux.Should().NotBeNull();
     result.Content.Bar.Should().NotBeNull();
     saved.Should().BeTrue(); 
}
```